# How to transfer video files from ipad air to macbook air

Tags: ios, ipad

There is no file explorer type utility in iOS just like we have it on Android system. So how can I copy files from/to my iPad from/to other computers (MacBook/Windows)? 
Specifically I am interested in the video created by the iOS Camera app.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to sync the whole library with iTunes there are plenty of other things you can do, but most require network connection:

- Apple's Photos app
- Image Capture
- Airdrop (as mentioned above)
- Since you mention file system access, and non-wireless transfer that would only be possible with 3rd party utilities (iMazing, iExplorer, PhoneView and more...) I won’t post links here, sure you’ll be able to find yourself.

Disclosure: I work with the iMazing team.

Answer (score 0):

Use AirDrop. With the video selected on the iPad, and the MB Finder in AirDrop, chose the Share button (box w/ curved arrow), then find and chose AirDrop.

**EDIT:** See [Import photos and videos from your iOS device to MAC or Windows](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201302)

Answer (score 0):

I use Dropbox's automatic Camera Upload feature. If you've installed Dropbox on your computers, they should start downloading the videos as soon as the iPad has uploaded them.

Comment: The Dropbox (and other cloud-based solutions) are good but they limit me to have a working internet connection. What if I don't have the internet connection at the moment, or is it too much slow to upload MBs of data.